# Qt Creator(Mac) + CUDA

Tags: macos, cuda, qt-creator

How to connect on a Mac: Qt Creator and CUDA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little uncertain of your question:

### 1. Implement portions of Qt Creator backend in CUDA?

Personally, I don't think that Qt Creator would be greatly improved (with the added complexity of optional installation requirements) by using CUDA in it's backend.  However, *to answer your question*, I would suggest that you think about writing plugins for very specific computationally intensive operations in the creator -- much like some of the plugins [have been developed for Gimp](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=76481) <- That's just an example, there are several more via [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Gimp+CUDA&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  I don't forsee any unusual OSX specific issue which you would encounter -- but feel free to post further questions if you hit such things.

### 2. Qt Graphical Interface + CUDA for Computation?

**If you want to create a Qt GUI which also performs some computationally intensive operations,** then I would suggest that you think modularly.  Again, I would suggest offloading the computationally intensive operation to a library which can then be 'farmed out' to CUDA.  Separating your GUI & computation (especially in threads) can make everything much more responsive.  And once you have your computation in a logically separate program/dll/library, then it is no different from any other CUDA implementation on a Mac.  I would recommend going to the [CUDA tutorials website](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-education-training) & watching the videos to get you started.

### Lastly:  Read this blog

I would strongly suggest reading through [this simple page](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1501) which deals directly with CUDA + Qt + Xcode.